# Post-fit distribution

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, statistics

In experimental particle physics papers, often one reads "pre-fit" and "post-fit" distribution as the caption of some kinematic distribution of data and simulation.

What is meant by "pre-fit" and "post-fit"?

Answer (score 1):

In **Bayesian statistics** we incorporate the our "initial believe/knowledge" into the analysis. This is done via the so called *prior distribution*. After the fit our "believe/knowledge" has been changed due to the incorporation of the new data. Therefore, we have obtained the so called *posterior distribution*. The two names, prior and posterior, are with respect to the gain of new data.

### An example:

Suppose you performed an experiment with $N_1=1000$ experimental units and found that the average value of some quantity is $\hat{\mu}_1=1$. Some times later, I perform an analog experiment using $N_2=300$ samples. The average value of my sample is $\hat{\mu}_2=1.5$. How do I incorporate your data into my analysis? There exists simple formulas for doing so. However, if we are not interested in a single quantity (i.e. the average value), but in the "distribution of knowledge", I would use your dataset to define a prior distribution. Fitting my "new" dataset using this prior distribution results in a combination of our datasets. We obtain the posterior distribution, which describes the current state of knowledge.

Comment: Dear Semoi, thank you very much for your explanation, but what does exactly change, i.e. what is the difference between the "pre-fit" simulation distribution and the "post-fit" distribution?

Comment: We have included the new dataset.